# Laravel install on Ubuntu16.04 get http error500

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

Laravel install on Ubuntu16.04 get

> HTTP error 500

My local site is working fine. After a push to a server, it got HTTP error 500. Someone told me a **run composer**. Since some reason, i cannot run composer on the production. I found the error log say:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/html/myProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderUtils.php
>   on line 21

My php version is 7.3.3 should be fine.

Comment: You pushed the vendor dir to live server!?

Comment: I think that you need to change PHP version (Read this [Link 1](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/composer.json#L19), [Link 2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this) )

Comment: yup~ I pushed the vendor dir to live server. @bmatovu

Comment: That is not a standard practice; you should gitignore it, then run composer update from the live server